# Jasper Reports table column filter data with multiple values through Visualize JS

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports, visualize

Last few days I was trying to integrate Jasper Reports to a application using Visualize JS.I have functionality to implement filter the Jasper Report column data by multiple values.The jasper report table has country column.

For example I have to filter records using user given texts.
[image]

So I have found an example in Visualize JS documentation and it is used only for one given text.

```
$("#setStringContains").on("click", 
 function() { report.updateComponent("country", {
   filter: {
     operator: "contain",
     value: $("#country").val() // example: country1
      } 
    }).fail(handleError);
});
```

I have to implement this with multiple text values as given previous picture.
I have tried to put 'Country1','Country2' in value element and it does not filter the table as I expected.It gives empty result table, so it takes the filter text as one value.

Comment: Are you asking about JasperReports Server?

Comment: No , I am trying to filter the data through Visualize.js. Jasper report is    available in Jasper server

Comment: JasperReports table column filters, in general, are not multi-value filters. You may want to resort to the [input control](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-visualizejs-guide/v640/api-reference-inputcontrols) functionality of JasperServer and Visualize for what you want.

Comment: @Narcis Thank you, now I am trying to parse data through params: property and parse those data to the query